# Is there a construct like "iterate iterable if it has elements, else ..."?

Tags: python, language-agnostic

Is there a more compact way to iterate an iterable if it has elements, or do something else if it hasn't?

My "problem" is in Python but I'd be interested in other languages as well.

Currently I test the number of elements first:

```
In [1]: l=[]

In [2]: if l:
   ...:     for e in l:
   ...:         print(e)
   ...: else:
   ...:     print("else")
   ...:
else
```

The [`for` statement has an `else`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement):

```
In [2]: for e in []:
   ...:     print(e)
   ...: else:
   ...:     print("else")
   ...:
else
```

but its "suite" (block) is also executed when the iteration is completed:

```
In [1]: for e in [1,2,3]:
   ...:     print(e)
   ...: else:
   ...:     print("else")
   ...:
1
2
3
else
```

I realize there is not much to gain here (one line and indent level) but I am curious if something like this exists.

Comment: Most of the time you just test for length and exit early: `if not l: # empty case, return`.

Comment: I've included test output with the first example to double-check the issue you pointed out before your edit...

Comment: *"I'd be interested in other languages as well"* – there will be widely differing approaches to this in various languages, it's a bit out of scope to talk about all of them here.

Comment: You are probably right about the scope, it may be limited to constructs that exists for the exact purpose (e.g. an `else` that would behave differently).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the time you just test for length and exit early:

```
if not l:
    # empty case
    return  # or raise exception
```

At any rate, because iteration *will not take place* on an empty list, the following is also sufficient, no `else` required:

```
if not l:
    # empty case
for i in l:
    # only ever executed if there are any elements
```

The `for ... else` suite is only useful for loops that *exit early*; the `else` suite is executed for all loops that *completed*. If a `break` was used the `else` is skipped. This makes it unsuitable for detecting empty sequences, as iteration on those completes successfully regardless of the number of elements in the absence of a `break` statement.

Comment: Too obvious :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you ask for other languages, here is Squeak/Pharo Smalltalk, since the paradigms are sufficiently close to Python:

you would write something like:

```
aCollection
    ifEmpty: [Transcript cr; show: 'else']
    ifNotEmpty: [aCollection do: [:each | Transcript cr; show: each printString]].
```

You could as well create a new method in Collection:

```
ifNotEmptyDo: aBlock elseDo: elseBlock
    self isEmpty ifTrue: [^elseBlock value].
    ^self do: aBlock
```

Then use it like this:

```
aCollection
    ifNotEmptyDo: [:each | Transcript cr; show: each printString]
    elseDo: [Transcript cr; show: 'else'].
```

Note that isEmpty is defined as `^self size = 0` by default, which is an heresy for possibly lazy or infinite collections... So I propose this new definition:

```
isEmpty
    self do: [:each |^false].
    ^true
```

Just to see that testing emptyness or performing a loop is more or less the same task ;)

**Conclusion**, in Smalltalk there is a very low level of syntactic sugar.
The block closures enable differed, conditional, or repeated evaluation.
Thus all the constructs like branches and loops and combinations of these are just ordinary messages taking block closures as parameters and you can add your own construct at will.
This facility is often abused with overkill selectors for a very small added value, so the need for new constructs should allways be put in balance with the maintenance cost (more methods to implement, test, and learn for a newcomer, etc...). Let's remember: "*Small is beautiful*".